# iOS Metal - what happens to a position with [[position]] qualifier when sent to fragment shader?

Tags: ios, metal

I am trying to understand how a float4 is changed in the fragment shader when the [[position]] qualifier is attached to it. I tried to pass same position, once with the qualider and once without and the result in the fragment shader were completely different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `[[position]]` output from the vertex shader is in normalized device coordinates. The `[[position]]` input to the fragment shader is in window coordinates. ("Window" coordinates is a bit of a misnomer. They are the coordinates within the render target attachment bounds, in pixels.) The relationship between these is the viewport that's been set. (If no viewport is explicitly set, the bounds of the attachment are used.)

[Metal Programming Guide: Graphics Rendering: Render Command Encoder](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/MetalProgrammingGuide/Render-Ctx/Render-Ctx.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014221-CH7-SW34):

> ### Working with Viewport and Pixel Coordinate Systems
>
> Metal defines its Normalized Device Coordinate (NDC) system as a 2x2x1
>   cube with its center at (0, 0, 0.5). The left and bottom for x and y,
>   respectively, of the NDC system are specified as -1. The right and top
>   for x and y, respectively, of the NDC system are specified as +1.
>
> The viewport specifies the transformation from NDC to the window
>   coordinates. The Metal viewport is a 3D transformation specified by
>   the `setViewport:` method of `MTLRenderCommandEncoder`. The origin of
>   the window coordinates is in the upper-left corner.

For other vertex outputs, the conversion to the fragment shader input depends on the sampling and interpolation qualifiers. If no qualifier is specified, it defaults to `center_perspective`. The qualifiers ending with `_perspective` use perspective-correct interpolation. Those ending with `_no_perspective` use linear interpolation. Those using `flat` specifier are not interpolated; the value from the provoking (i.e. first) vertex of the primitive is passed unchanged to the fragment shader.